# Leibniz's rule application

Tags: calculus

I need to show whether the following serie converges or diverges:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+100}$$

I need to use ONLY Leibniz's rule. I started by writing:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}(- \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+100})$$

Now I wanted to show that $- \dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{n+100}$ decreases but I am having trouble showing that.

Can someone help me please.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Well, since the sequence $\,\displaystyle{\frac{\sqrt n}{n+100}}\,$ is *eventually* monotone converging to zero (why?), Leibnitz theorem/test applies here and thus your series converges.

Oh, and it really doesn't matter, for convergence purposes, whether you being with a positive or a negative summand in the series.

Comment: Can you detail a little more the monotony illustration please ?

Comment: It is NOT converging monoton as you can see in my answer. The sequence is increasing from n=0 to 100 and decreasing monoton for $n>100$.

Comment: Yeah, well: you're right, @Fant, but the text applies for *eventually* monotone sequences. Point taken though, thanks.

Comment: @Fant: You want just a starting point in this test.

Comment: @BabakSorouh:  I know. Anyhow the sequence is not monoton for all n. That's why I just gave a comment (so DonAntonio might improve his answer) and didn't downvote the answer or sth like that.

Answer (score 2):

You have 
$$\frac{d}{dn}\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+100}\right) = \frac{100-n}{2\sqrt{n}(n+100)^2}$$
which is $\lt 0 \ \ \forall n  \gt 100$.

That's why $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+100}$ decreases monotonically for $n>100$.

Comment: I hope, you accept my edit just for the derivation. It needs parentheses.

Comment: Like your attempt.